# Optimizar una Sql quitando el with

Tags: sql

Tengo que calcular la venta media por tienda-articulo de las Últimas 7 semanas completas.

Es decir si hoy es Miércoles **25/07/2018**, tomaría la venta correspondiente desde el **04/06/18** al **22/07/2018**. Para posicionarme en esas fechas he utilizado el `next_day()`.

En la primera sentencia, busco los días realmente abiertos que ha tenido cada tienda desde el **04/06/2018** al **22/07/2018** y me lo guardo.

Y esos días luego los utilizo en la segunda sentencia para la media suma venta en el periodo/ números de días.

No estoy muy convencida de la estructura, habría otra forma mejor para calcular el dato?

```
With P1 as(select VECTIE,COUNT (DISTINCT VEFVTD) AS DVENTA from xxxx where VEFVTD BETWEEN (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 55 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) AND  (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 7 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) 
GROUP BY VECTIE)

SELECT A.VECTIE, VECPRO,                                
    CAST((SUM(VECVTD)/DVENTA) AS DECIMAL( 9, 3)) VECVTD,  
    CAST((SUM(VECVGR)/DVENTA) AS DECIMAL( 9, 3)) VECVGR   
FROM xxxx A INNER JOIN P1 ON A.VECTIE=P1.VECTIE                                        
WHERE VEFVTD BETWEEN (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 55 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) AND  (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 7 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) 

GROUP BY A.VECTIE, VECPRO ,DVENTA
```

Comment: que motor utilizas?

Comment: por lo que veo es sqlServer, no sera mejor que realices un SP ? de ser asi, utilizaria la funcion DATEADD() tomaria las 7 semanas (cada una en una variable) y luego trabajaria con ellas.

Comment: Gracias Francisco. No sabría como hacerlo como tu dices. Mis conocimientos son bastantes básicos. Si me sacas de lo que se me pierdo.

Comment: déjame bajar el motor y lo vemos...

Comment: Gracias Francisco

Answer (score 0):

Y asi no mas no te anda:

```
SELECT A.VECTIE, VECPRO,                                
    CAST((SUM(VECVTD)/COUNT (DISTINCT VEFVTD)) AS DECIMAL( 9, 3)) VECVTD,  
    CAST((SUM(VECVGR)/COUNT (DISTINCT VEFVTD)) AS DECIMAL( 9, 3)) VECVGR   
FROM xxxx A INNER JOIN xxxx1 B ON A.VECTIE=B.VECTIE                                        
WHERE VEFVTD BETWEEN (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 55 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) AND  (SELECT DATE(NEXT_DAY(CURRENT DATE,'SUNDAY')- 7 DAYS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) 

GROUP BY A.VECTIE, VECPRO ,VEFVTD
```

Quedo atento

Comment: Gracias Michael. Lo pruebo y te digo. Tiene muy buena pinta.

Comment: Hola, no me ejecuta la consulta. Se queda pensando y no lanza. No obstante a lponer en el select la tienda(vectie) y el producto (vecpro) el count distinct de los días  venta (vefvtd) no es correcto. Porque saldrá las fechas diferentes de venta que hay por articulo. Y realmente hay que dividirlo por las fechas diferentes que exista en la tienda.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una subconsulta, quitando los días "no realmente abiertos" y trabajar sobre ella en la segunda consulta que agregas con un alias

Comment: Realmente es lo que estoy haciendo con el with. Cuentos los días realmente abiertos de la tienda y aplico el numero en la segunda subconsulta. Y el resultado es correcto.. simplemente que me gustaría no tener que utilizar el WITH.